# Component Constructors In HappyX

Tags: web, constructor, web-component, nim-lang

It possible to create custom component constructor in happyx web framework?
For example:

```
component A:
  field: int
  
  constructor(args):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeap, it possible. Few hours ago this [issue](https://github.com/HapticX/happyx/issues/79) was closed in HappyX repo.

So to declare constructor you need

```
component A:
  field: int
  constructor(a: int):
    self.field = a*5
```

And usage is

```
appRoutes "app":
  "/":
    component A->construct(a = 10)
```

Comment: Ethosa, please see the section on [self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), and "disclose your affiliation in your post". Thank you.

Comment: Both accounts were created 6 days ago. One account asks the questions, the other (the HappyX developer) answers the questions within minutes, then the first accounts marks the answer as the correct one within minutes... Hey, you have to be creative on Stack Overflow to promote HappyX